# How do I populate a column with the results of sorting another column?

Tags: excel-2010

Column A has names. There are a whole bunch of stats next to each name and then in column K those stats are calculated into a value (1.26-206). What I'm trying to do is sort column K lowest to highest and place the corresponding column A names in a sorted list in column M. I don't want this procedure to change the order of anything at all in any column other than column M.

For example

```
A                   K
John                5
Bill                102
Caitlyn             3.21
```

I want to make it show:

```
A                   K           M
John                5           Caitlyn
Bill                102         John
Caitlyn             3.21        Bill
```

And if It could also show the values of each name in N like so:

```
A                   K           M         N
John                5           Caitlyn   3.21
Bill                102         John      5
Caitlyn             3.21        Bill      102
```

That would be even more amazing.

To be honest I'm not 100% convinced its even possible. Every time I search to see if this is possible I just get tutorials on how to select a column and sort that column which changes the order of that column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not sorting the columns directly?
In case you still need to sort the columns in M and N. Paste the names to column M and the stats from column K to column N and then sort the M & N column by selecting them both. Choose not to extend the selection.

Hope this should work for you.